# Updated Excel sheet through Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

I have placed an excel file in my eclipse (Luna) work space so that it appears in the folder structure of the IDE. But if I try to update the sheet through the IDE the changes don't get saved. Is there anyway that I can save the changes when the sheet is opened from Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not occur for me with Spring Tool Suite 3.3.0 and any edit is seen outside of STS. So it's either a configuration issue or a bug.

Have you tried right click and Open with System editor? This will launch Excel external to the IDE.